# TLS Connection Looking For Wallet in Default Location despite using MY_WALLET_DIRECTORY

Tags: oracle, tnsnames, tls-1.2

I'm finding hints here and there that this is a known issue, but just wanted to ask here directly to confirm. I have a typical client-server TLS connection. We have multiple database instances server-side, each with their own client-side apps, and are transitioning all of them to communicating over TLS1.2. We would like to avoid making unique sqlnet.ora files for all of them, so are opting to use each client's tnsnames.ora file to point to where the wallet is on the server-side. That is my understanding of how the MY_WALLET_DIRECTORY is supposed to work.

Client side tnsnames.ora uses the MY_WALLET_DIRECTORY parameter as follows:

```
(SECURITY=

(SSL_SERVER_CERT_DN=[cert])

(MY_WALLET_CONNECTION=[location of server-side wallet])

)
```

This results in ORA-28759: failure to open file. Looking at the trace, it is clear that it is looking for the server-side wallet in the default Unix area:

```
[29-AUG-2022 11:00:59:766] snzdfo_open_file: Opening file /etc/ORACLE/WALLETS/oracle/ewallet.p12 with READ ONLY permissions

[29-AUG-2022 11:00:59:767] snzdfo_open_file: File Open/Close error

[29-AUG-2022 11:00:59:767] nzdfo_open: File Open/Close error

[29-AUG-2022 11:00:59:768] nziropen: rio open failed with error 28759
```

This error is eliminated if the WALLET_LOCATION parameter is set in the server-side sqlnet.ora file, but that gets us back to the problem of then having to create unique sqlnet.ora directories for each instance. Hopefully this is just something I'm not understanding. Thanks for any assistance you can provide.

ETA: This is a 19c database.

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using? `MY_WALLET_CONNECTION` isn't documented. Per Oracle 21c docs here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/netrf/local-naming-parameters-in-tns-ora-file.html#GUID-E48103F6-8B8B-457C-9374-695C7CCAD816 the correct parameter to use in tnsnames.ora is still `WALLET_LOCATION`.

Comment: Also note that this parameter usage appears to be new with Oracle 21c. If you're using an older version of the client or server, this parameter in tnsnames.ora would not apply at all.

Answer (score 0):

So figured out it was a mix of a typo and not understanding what the MY_WALLET_DIRECTORY tnsnames.ora parameter did (MY_WALLET_CONNECTION was a typo that I didn't see for some reason). This is meant for when there are multiple wallets on a single client; it does not point to the server-side wallet. The location of the server-side wallet is exclusively recorded in the server-side sqlnet.ora file.

Supposedly I can use a single wallet on the server-side across multiple instances by adding additional user certificates, but that is presenting it's own problems where the only app that will connect to its database with this wallet is the app corresponding to the database whose user cert was put into the wallet first. Which one was added to the wallet first can be seen with `orapki wallet display`.

Would best practice in this case be to create another question for using a shared server-side wallet across multiple server instances and client apps, or to just continue in this one?